# Making a <td> accessible as a link in a table via tabbing

Tags: html, angular, wai-aria

I have this table and within it a have a `<td>` tag in which the user can click on it and it will navigate to a different page. Currently when I click it works fine, but when I am using my keyboard and try to press enter on the link it doesn't take me anywhere and I wanted to know how can I make it keyboard accessible with out have to convert it to a button.

This is what I have:

```
<td role="gridcell">
    <a (click)="userClicked(user)">{{user.Name}}</>
</td>
```

I tried using a span instead of an `<a>` tag but still no luck.

```
<td role="gridcell">
    <span role="button" tabindex="0" (click)="userClicked(user)">{{user.Name}}</span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `(keyup.enter)`

```
<a href="#" (keyup.enter)="userClicked(user)">{{user.Name}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<button>` element instead, that is working fine.

I had problems with just selecting the `<a>` tag at all by clicking `tab` key, but that might be different problem (as I am trying that on existing project).

```
<td><button (click)="test()">TEST</button></td>
```

**EDIT**

Your problem is that you do not have the `href` attribute on your anchor, and it is therefore not focusable (as @Richard Medeiros noted here in comments). I just tested it, and its working just with the `(click)` binding.

Do not forget to return `false` from the handler, so you do not follow the `href` attribute:

```
<td><a href="#" (click)="test()">TEST</a></td>

test() {
    // ...
    return false;
}
```

Here is working example: https://angular-playground-1ji4ko.stackblitz.io

Comment: If you add an `href` to the `<a>` tag it will be tab-able

Comment: I've simply gotta ask - how/why does the `(click)` part work? I've never seen it before, and when testing it myself in a fiddle it simply won't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: well I have put alert in the handler, and when I have focus on the tag pressing enter shows the alert...

Comment: and why? because when you have focus on the `<a>` element, pressing enter basically clicks it (by default that follows the `href` attribute).

Comment: @MartinAdámek sure, but i mean - how/why does the bracketed `(click)` work? the one I know is `onclick="test()"` such as [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/xa7L4s8q/3/) - but I've never seen the bracketed version "`(click)`"?

Comment: That is angular syntax of event binding, more about that here https://angular.io/guide/user-input